# Multiple users in Login Session

Tags: java, struts2

I'm a fresh Struts2 Beginner... and now I'm making a little project...
but now I'm in trouble... :(
My Project is a kind of Fan Club and I want to allow multiple users in my site..
it's smoothly run on localhost and can access...
it has posting photo, and pdf file.. that's all ok
But in appsrv, I can't post anything...and login session in trouble...
eg. user A is currently log in and run on his pages. At the same time, user B log in.
And then user A's page is turned user B's page by user B.
Please you can answer this question, as soon as possible reply to me..

Comment: provide at least some code. How are you storing the currently logged user?

Comment: I put Login Session in every jsp and java pages.. but it can't hold login user... 

in .java 
ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put("loginName",loginName); ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put("userID", userID); 

in jsp page 
<% ActionContext.getContext().getSession().get("loginName")%>